# Get RouteId value from the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following action button on a View. The view is located on InventoryRequest Index (list). So when the button is clicked, it will redirect to another view which is InventoryRequestDetails - Index:

```
<a asp-controller="InventoryRequestDetails" asp-action="Index" 
   asp-route-id="@item.InventoryRequestId">Details</a>
```

Then on the InventoryRequestDetails Controller - Index. I put the following code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int InventoryRequestId)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Finding InventoryRequest with ID {InventoryRequestId}");

    // Select the InventoryRequest object with the specified InventoryRequestId
    var inventoryRequest = await _context.InventoryRequests.FindAsync(InventoryRequestId);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Found InventoryRequest: {inventoryRequest}");

    // Check if an InventoryRequest object was found
    if (inventoryRequest == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Store the value of the RequestNumber property in a ViewBag object
    ViewBag.RequestNumber = inventoryRequest.RequestNumber;

    // Retrieve the InventoryRequestDetails data for the specified InventoryRequestId
    var applicationDbContext = _context.InventoryRequestDetails
        .Include(i => i.Inventaris)
        .Include(i => i.InventoryRequest)
        .Where(w => w.InventoryRequestId == InventoryRequestId);

    // Return the view with the InventoryRequestDetails data and the RequestNumber value in the ViewBag
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

The thing is, I couldn't get the RouteID that has been passed into the URL in InventoryRequestDetails. The URL is something like this:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/InventoryRequestDetails/Index/1
```

I want to get the `Id` value which is "1" on the URL above. How can I do that? Are there any mistakes in my code? Please advise.

After I get the value, I want to create another list which is filtered by the value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three approaches to fix:

1. Change the `asp-route` name: `asp-route-inventoryRequestId`

```
<a asp-controller="InventoryRequestDetails" asp-action="Index" asp-route-inventoryRequestId="@item.InventoryRequestId">Details</a>
```

2. In the controller action, change the property name `InventoryRequestId` to `id`.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
```

3. Work with the route:

```cs
[HttpGet("{InventoryRequestId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int InventoryRequestId)
```

Reference: [Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#example)